# knitting multiple html files rstudio

Tags: html, r, markdown, knitr, rstudio

I have a chunk of code that I want to run on multiple data files. For example I want summary statistics of all the data files. For each file, I need a separate HTML file (knit html). Is there a way to run the code on all the files producing separate HTML files for each data file respectively, apart from running the code on each file individually and then knitting and then "saving as" on RStudio??

Here is an example of code I want to run on each file:

```
summary(myData$ZScoreA)

boxplot(myData$ZScoreA, myData$ZScoreB, main="ZScores", xlab="Group", ylab="ZScore value", names=c("A","B"))

plot(myData$ZScoreA)

library(ggplot2)

qplot(ZScoreA, data=myData)
```

Comment: You may want: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brew/index.html  Here's a robot's blog post on using it: http://botthoughts.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/generating-reports-for-different-data-sets-using-brew-and-knitr/

Comment: Thanks! this is really useful. Do you think I can use the .Rmd format instead of .Rnw like he did???

Comment: Sure why not.  It works on files not specific files.

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like you should write your code using a function.

```
yourfunction <- (yourdata) {summary(yourdata$ZScoreA)
boxplot(yourdata$ZScoreA, yourdata$ZScoreB, main="ZScores", xlab="Group", ylab="ZScorevalue", names=c("A","B"))
plot(yourdata$ZScoreA)
library(ggplot2)
qplot(ZScoreA, data=yourdata)
}
```

Call you function on all your data

```
yourfunction(yourdata1)
yourfunction(yourdata2)
yourfunction(yourdata3)
```

Brew looks likes it can help you write the data from yourfunction to html.